# How to build html documentation dev version in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to build Html documentation for postgresql-15. for postgresql current version I can get the `postgresql-14.2.tar.gz` then unzip then I can get the offline html file.

By following https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/docguide-toolsets.html

I did
`sudo apt-get install docbook-xml docbook-xsl fop libxml2-utils xsltproc`
then cd to `CLionProjects/postgres_15/doc/src/sgml`
then run command `make html` then error happened.

```
Makefile:26: ../../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '../../../src/Makefile.global'.  Stop.
```

Then I run `cat Makefile` in `../../../src` folder return the following part.

```
# doc/src/Makefile

subdir = doc/src
top_builddir = ../..
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global

all distprep html man install installdirs uninstall clean distclean maintainer-clean:
        $(MAKE) -C sgml $@
```

In https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/docguide-toolsets.html

> Before you can build the documentation you need to run the configure
> script, as you would when building the PostgreSQL programs themselves.
> Check the output near the end of the run; it should look something
> like this:

This part I don't understand. Therefore this part I skipped.

Comment: You can't skip that part. You need to run `./configure` at the top level of the unzipped source. That would be where the `configure` program is located. It is what builds the `Make` file that is not currently being found.  See [Build from source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/install-procedure.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  there is no unzipped code in https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v14.2/. I pull it from https://github.com/postgres/postgres. I don't know how to run ./configure. There is a only folder called config. I just want to get html doc...

Comment: You said you downloaded `postgresql-14.2.tar.gz` and unzipped it. Is that not the case? If not do `tar -xzvf postgresql-14.2.tar.gz` and that should get you a directory like `postgresql-14.2/`. `cd` into that directory and run `./configure`. Then do the doc build. There are no HTML docs shipped, the documentation is in SGML and you have to run the `make` to build the HTML.